# How to extract data from a website using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want from a GET request to stackoverflow.com to read the HTML, then capture CSRF-token and store it in a variable.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="CIwNZNlR4XbisJF39I8yWnWX9wX4WFoz" />
```

I want to use stored token for a post request. Is it possible?

Comment: probably `document.querySelector("input[name=csrf-token]").value` to access that value

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I think there are many tutorials on blogs and video tutorials on YouTube which show how to scrape in Python. It needs `requests`/`urllib` + `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, or [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). It need also to learn `CSS selectors` or `XPATH selectors` to select elements in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this completely in browser then

```
// on csrf token page
let csrfTokenValue = document.querySelector("input[name=csrf-token]").value
        localStorage.setItem('csrfTokenValue', csrfTokenValue);


// on another page
document.querySelector("input[name=csrf-token]").value = localStorage.getItem('csrfTokenValue');
```

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is used for persisting this value for page reload/change.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, it can't be done the way you want.

CSRF means Cross Site Request Forgery, and is precisely designed to prevent what you want to do. And it is not the only challenge you would face.

First, this is how a JavaScript code to fetch the contents of a website would look.

```
fetch('https://www.google.es')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

If you run this code, wou will likely get an error saying something like "the request has been blocked due to same origin policy", or something similar.

When making a JavaScript request, the browser enforces it to be from the same origin, unless the owner of the site specifically allows requests from different domains by setting a header named **Access-control-allow-origin:**

**How to fetch contents from a website then?**

You can fetch the contents of a website using server side technologies. The problem described above will affect you when you execute a request within a browser, but the same restriction doesn't apply when you make a request using **CURL** command, for example.

Now, assuming that you make a curl request to fetch the contents, you may find that the contents are not what you expect. Many modern websites won't serve the entire content directly, and rather, generate part, or even all of its content using JavaScript.

**Enter headless browsers**

A headless browser is a browser without visual interface that you can handle programatically. With it, you can navigate to a page, wait for it to load, and extract it contents, even if they are dynamically loaded.

Some years ago, before I learned the hard way to reject any job related to webscrapping in the future, I used PhantomJS, but its development was suspended some years ago, so I suggest to search for an alternative.

Basically, the way you operate a headless browser would be something like this (not real code):

```
browser.start();
browser.navigateTo("google.es");
browser.waitUntilNetworkIdle(); //We wait until the browser stops making requests to load dynamic content.
contents = browser.getContents();
csrfToken = getCsrfToken();
....
```

Roughly, this is how you would get the CSRF token from a page, and then, you can use it to make further requests within the page.

But there are more challenges you have to take into account.

In first place, CSRF tokens are usually tied to the current session, so you cannot store it to use it later as you suggest. You would have to do everythin in the same session.

Also, usually, different requests may use different CSRF tokens, so you would have to find the correct csrfToken for different requests within the same site.

And last but not least, the site you are trying to scrap may have mechanisms in place to avoid automated tools. Have you ever seen the "prove you are human" popup? guess what, it is actually a problem for automated tools like headless browsers.

**What would I do**

Given the possiblity, reject the job. But if that's not a possiblity, I would create an API endpoint in my server:

```
api/getPage1Contents
api/getPage2Contents
...
```

When making a request to one of those endpoints, I would launch a headless browser and run an automated script (as explained above) to extract the contents. Then, I would return those contents in the response, and use them as needed. Still, keep in mind that you may find captchas, rate limits, and any other tools whose only purpose is to prevent you from accesing contents in an automated way.

**TLDR**

Webscrapping is hard task, and albeit technically it can be achieved, it requires high skills with JavaScript and a deep knowledge of HTML structures, using multiple tools/programming languages, may have legal implications, and you may find unsolvable problems down the road.

Unless your job involves webscrapping as an everyday task, I would steer clear of it.